# auctex 11.88 bug(?) on LaTeX-env-label, cannot automatically insert label

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

I have recently been trying auctex 11.88 on emacs 24.4(win7+mac). it's great so far!

I used to have the following in my .emacs emacs file when I was using auctex11.87 (I bumped into it on stackexchange somewhere)

```lisp
(setq reftex-label-alist
  '(
    ("theorem" ?h "thm:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("theorem" "th."))
    ("lemma" ?l "lem:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("lemma" "lem." ))
    ("exercise" ?x "ex:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("exercise" "ex." ))
    ("question" ?q "ques:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("question" "q." ))
    ))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (LaTeX-add-environments
       '("lemma" LaTeX-env-label)
       '("exercise" LaTeX-env-label)
       '("theorem" LaTeX-env-label)
       '("question" LaTeX-env-label)
       )))

(setq  reftex-insert-label-flags '("s" "ft"))
```

It automatically generates a label when I insert a newly defined environment, say, when I run `C-c C-e exercise RET`, I get

```
\begin{exercise}
  \label{ex:1}
  (cursor here)
\end{exercise}
```

now in auctex11.88 I can only get

```
\begin{exercise}
  (cursor here)
\end{exercise}
```

I need to further run `C-c (` to add `\label{ex:1}` there.

I'm not sure if the lisp code I was using gets out dated. I tried executing the short piece `(LaTeX-env-label "exercise")`. In auctex11.87 I get the desired result, but not in auctex11.88.

Please advise! Thanks very much!

BTW, is it really a bug which is early mentioned in 
[the mail](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-emacs-windows/2014-11/msg00011.html)
or should we adjust something else in auctex11.88? Some new feature + backward compatibility issue is mentioned in 
[mailing list](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.bugs)
I'm not an expert on this, could anyone elaborate? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AUCTeX and RefTeX are two separated and independent packages, one can be used without the other.  AUCTeX has some facilities about labels and citations management, RefTeX is much better in doing this.

Not everyone uses RefTeX and there has been a change in AUCTeX 11.88 to let users choose which labels should be inserted.  This selection is independent from RefTeX, but as a side effect people need to customize another AUCTeX (not RefTeX) variable: `LaTeX-label-alist`.  Here is its description in the [manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002dlabel_002dalist)

> *User Option*: **LaTeX-label-alist**
>
> List the prefixes to be used for the label of each supported environment.
>
> This is an alist whose car is the environment name, and the cdr either the prefix or a symbol referring to one.
>
> If the name is not found, or if the cdr is nil, no label is automatically inserted for that environment.
>
> If you want to automatically insert a label for a environment but with an empty prefix, use the empty string `""` as the cdr of the
>   corresponding entry.

So you should also add an entry to `LaTeX-label-alist` for the `excercise` environment.  In your `.emacs`, replace the `add-hook` with this one

```lisp
(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (LaTeX-add-environments
    '("lemma" LaTeX-env-label)
    '("exercise" LaTeX-env-label)
    '("theorem" LaTeX-env-label)
    '("question" LaTeX-env-label))
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-label-alist '("exercise" . "ex:"))))
```

To avoid confusion: AUCTeX decide whether the label should be inserted or not looking at `LaTeX-label-alist`, but if RefTeX is enabled, and in particular if `LaTeX-label-function` is `reftex-label`, the insertion of the label is transferred to RefTeX and the label actually inserted is chosen by the value of a RefTeX variable, `reftex-label-alist`.

For RefTeX users the value of the CDR of the `exercise` entry in `LaTeX-label-alist` is almost useless, the important it's that it's a valid string.

The point of customizing `LaTeX-label-alist` is to have the same behavior for RefTeX and non-RefTeX users.

---

For clarity, this is the minimal `.emacs` I used for testing:

```lisp
;; Enable RefTeX automatically in AUCTeX buffers.
(autoload 'turn-on-reftex "reftex" "RefTeX Minor Mode" nil)
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (turn-on-reftex)))
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)

;; RefTeX-related settings.
(setq
 reftex-label-alist
 '(("theorem" ?h "thm:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("theorem" "th."))
   ("lemma" ?l "lem:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("lemma" "lem." ))
   ("exercise" ?x "ex:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("exercise" "ex." ))
   ("question" ?q "ques:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("question" "q." )))
 reftex-insert-label-flags '("s" "ft"))

;; AUCTeX-related settings.
(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (LaTeX-add-environments
    '("lemma" LaTeX-env-label)
    '("exercise" LaTeX-env-label)
    '("theorem" LaTeX-env-label)
    '("question" LaTeX-env-label))
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-label-alist '("exercise" . "ex:"))))
```

Comment: Many thanks! But still no luck...I added what you suggested (almost) `(add-to-list 'LaTeX-label-alist '("exercise" . "exx:"))`, but restarting emacs give me the error `Symbol's value as variable is void: LaTeX-label-alist`, and reloading the `.emacs` buffer did not casue any trouble. I checked that the variable `'LaTeX-label-alist` is now changed with `("exercise" . "exx:")` added. But back in the tex file `C-c C-e exercise RET` still does not work. Could you please look into this again? thanks.

Comment: @davyjones  There were two errors: I mistyped the name of the environment, and the `exercise` entry was added before the variable has been defined, that's why you got the void variable error, thanks for having pointed out it!  I keep forgetting about it `:-(`  Now it should work `;-)`

Comment: the void error seems to go away after adding `(require 'latex)`. I noticed the typo. But I never get the prompt for label after inserting environment. Even if I add label afterwards, I never get `exx:1` as expected. Is anthing else need to be taken care of? thanks!

Comment: @giodano, btw, I tried `lgathered` `rgathered` `multlined` in the bug report. None of them prompt for label. When I try to add label by `C-c (`, it prompt the section option `sec:`. Not sure if it's related. Also, trying `(setq LaTeX-label-alist (append '( ("lemma" . "lemm:") ("exercise" . "exx:") ) LaTeX-label-alist))` does not work either. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `require`, it's not needed at all. If you use RefTeX, the inserting of the label is demanded to RefTeX and the actual label is inserted by RefTeX (so the final label prefix is chosen by RefTeX), the entry in `LaTeX-label-alist` is needed to decide whether a label should be inserted or not, the value of the prefix is not really important when you use RefTeX, the important is that's non nil.

Comment: @davyjones  See the updated answer, I inserted the minimal `.emacs` I used for testing.

Comment: @giodano, It's working great! Thank you again so much! One more question (if I may). I had to use four `add-to-list` to accommodate more environments. It there any way to make it more compact? maybe just a single `add-to-list`-like function?

Comment: @davyjones  Unfortunately `add-to-list` accepts one argument at the time.  Is it for the `lemma`, `theorem`, and `question` environment?  I can make that more compact, if you want, using a loop.

Comment: @giodano, I thought `append` would work, but it does not. I'll try the loop when I got more than ten new environments :) Many thanks! You've made my day!